# How can i pass/copy the same selection?? So that i can run the multiple macros on same selection with single click.?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have to run the three macros with single click, when i call the first macro the selected word got reversed but the selection got lost and i think the selection got  deselected due to the change of the word(in reversed), but i need the selection to run the other macros on the same selection.

```
Dim oWord As Range

If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
    For Each cl In Selection.Cells
        Set rng = cl.Range
        rng.MoveEnd Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=-1
        For i = 1 To rng.Words.Count
            Set iRng = rng.Words(i)
            'rng.Select

            Set oWord = iRng
            Do While oWord.Characters.Last.Text = " "
                Call oWord.MoveEnd(WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1)
            Loop
            Debug.Print "'" & oWord.Text & "'"
            oWord.Text = StrReverse(oWord.Text)

            Debug.Print Selection.Text

        Next i
    Next cl
End If

End Sub
Sub Align()

'Selection.RtlPara
 Selection.LtrPara

 End Sub

 Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

 Call Align
 Call CommandButton1_Click
 Call Comma_Remove
 Call CommandButton1_Click

 End Sub

 Sub Comma_Remove()


Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ","
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

This picture illustrates the issues i received after changes to the code

[image]

Comment: Assign the selection range to a word.range. Then use the range.duplicate method to pass copies of the range as required.

Comment: Would you give me a dummy example so that i can understand where i am doing things wrong.

Comment: The picture isn't worth very much. Posting code in a picture is not within the site's rules - code (and error messages) should always be plain text. It would help a lot if you would post a sample of text you want to manipulate, another sample of what the result should be, and a sample of what the code you currently have actually does. Also describe what all the macros do - either in the problem description or using comments in the macros. The question is really not very clear.

Comment: Well i am trying my best to follow the site rules i am new here and people need to understand the concept so i have to upload the picture, second when i edit the code number of lines increased.. But from now on i am going to avoid the unnecessary details. Thank you for your corporation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I amended your code to show you what I mean.  I added the SelectedRange variable.  Selected range uses duplicate to make a copy of the selection range.  SelectedRange is set as a global variable for the purposes of your code. localRange is used in your macros where we make a copy of SelectedRange.

Edit 2018-12-20: Minor updates to the code to add option explicit, add missing declarations, make SelectedRange global and to replace the mysterious LtlPara with code to left align paragraphs

Edit 2018-12-21: revised code to reestablish selection and an explanation of why this is necessary.

The OP is selecting a range of cells in a table and then iterating over the cells to do a couple of transformations on the string in each cell.  Typically we would not use selection for all of these operations, instead we would set a word range and work with the word range.  In this specific case this runs into a problem because there is a difference between Selection and a word range when applied to a table.  The difference is that Selection.Cells.Count gives the number of of cells in the selection but selection.Range.Cells.count gives the number of cells in the table starting with the first cell in Selection.range, counting each cell in the table from left to right, row by row, until the last cell in the selection is reached.  This is why cells not in the selection are being processed when using a word range rather than the selection.

We can overcome this oddity by preserving the selection range in a word range and then restoring the selection using SelectedRange.Select for each sub that needs to work on the Selection.

```
Option Explicit
Public SelectedRange  As Word.Range

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim cl As Word.Cell
Dim Rng As Word.Range
Dim i As Long
Dim iRng As Word.Range
Dim oWord As Word.Range

    SelectedRange.Select
    If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then


        For Each cl In Selection.Cells
            Set Rng = cl.Range
            Rng.MoveEnd Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=-1
            For i = 1 To Rng.Words.Count
                Set iRng = Rng.Words(i)
                'rng.Select

                Set oWord = iRng
                Do While oWord.Characters.Last.Text = " "
                    Call oWord.MoveEnd(WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1)
                Loop
                Debug.Print "'" & oWord.Text & "'"
                oWord.Text = StrReverse(oWord.Text)

                Debug.Print Selection.Text

            Next i
        Next cl
    End If

End Sub
Sub Align()
Dim localrange As Word.Range

    'Set localrange = SelectedRange.Duplicate
    SelectedRange.Select
    'Selection.RtlPara
    Selection.Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Set SelectedRange = Selection.Range.Duplicate 'make a copy of the selection range
    Align
    CommandButton1_Click
    Comma_Remove
    CommandButton1_Click

End Sub

Sub Comma_Remove()

    SelectedRange.Select

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ","
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: Some how i mange to run the code and code work as i needed but not on the selected selection. The macro run on the all the non selected words as well ?

Comment: It is your code.  All I have done is replace Selection with localrange .What did you mean when you wrote it originally.  If you intended to left align paragraphs then the line should be localrange.paragraphs.paragraphformat.alignment=wdalignparagraphright.  I'd suggest you put Option Explicit at the top of your module.

Comment: Oh great it worked but now one other issued appeared now align macro run on the non selected words, and when forth call is running the last selected value remains the same.

Comment: In which case you need to provide  an explanation of what you are trying to achieve.  Additionally it might be helpful if you provide examples of your document showing how it appears before and how you wish it to appear afterwards.

Comment: See the above attached picture plz.

Comment: i want to reverse the selected words then remove the commas and then reverse the same selected words again. This is what i am trying  to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the image.  Its now clear what you want and also why there are issues.  When you select a range of cells in a table the number of cells in Selection.Cells.Count and Selection.Range.Count don't match.  Selection.Range.Cells gives all the cells starting at the first in the selection, then counting left across each row in the table (including cells outside the selection) until the last cell in the selection is reached.  This is a very frustrating difference between selection and selection.range (and hence why SelectedRange is causing your macros to behave incorrectly.

Comment: Select a range of cells in your table and then print the results of selection.cells.count and selection.range.cells.count. In the short term it means that you have to go back and use Selection BUT you use the selectedrange to reset the selection in each macro.  So rather than Set localrange = SelectedRange.Duplicate, change to SelectedRange.Select to reset the selection and change the use of selectedrange back to selection e.g. localrange.Find.ClearFormatting to Selection.Find.Clearformatting etc.  I'll update the code for tomorrow as I'm stuck in meetings for the rest of today.

Comment: Waiting for your updated response. Thanks for your time and help in advance.